# VBScript - SQLOLEDB from CSV File - Invalid Connection String Attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, connection-string

I am trying to execute a very simple example of using SQLOLEBD to retrieve records from a CSV file using VBScript.
I am getting the error:
Line: 4 
Char: 1 
Error: Invalid connection string attribute" 
Code: 80004005
Source: Microsoft OLD DB Provider for SQL Server
Can somebody please straighten me out?

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source= C:\Users\public\; Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM employees.csv, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText"

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
Wscript.Echo "name: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("Name")
objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

wscript.echo "Finished"
```

---

employees.csv

id,name,grade
1,"Ezequiel, Justin",1
2,Charlie Sheen,4
3,"Name, Your",8
4,Another Guy,16

Comment: SQLOLEDB is for connections to SQL Server, why are you trying to use it to open a text file? http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

Comment: Um, because I don't know any better.

Comment: My goal is to join the data with other data from a SQL Server table, and spit out the output to another CSV file.

Comment: When I try to use Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, I get a Provider Not Found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error is using the wrong OLE DB provider (your Jet provider error might be a [32-bit vs 64-bit issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/the-microsoftjetoledb40-provider-is-not-registered/40de1d9d-98f2-4526-8e6a-a4e611b92760)), but it appears that your real goal is to join data in a text file with data in a table.

Two fairly simple options are a) load the file into a SQL Server table using one of the various [bulk loading methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx) and then join the tables as usual, or b) join the table on the file directly using [OPENROWSET()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx). If you'll do this a lot, or if you have a lot of data, the first approach is probably better because you can leverage the database engine for indexing and better join performance.

You could use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) for this too, but it's probably overkill in this scenario.

And mentioning your SQL Server version and other specific details is always useful.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Yes, you were right on several points.  I understand now that I was using the wrong OLE DB provider.  And yes, I see that my problem trying to use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 was a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue.  My data is in small enough daily chunks that I will try to figure out your option b) OPENROWSET().  I will remember in the future to provide version information.

Comment: No problem. FYI, if you find an answer on SO helpful, it's considered polite to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)